How to focus on a specific country on button click in Leaflet.js
When using Leaflet.js and the global map, how can I focus on a specific country after pressing a button?
I know I can set the map view to a specific latitude and longitude via:
map.setView({lat: 40.25, lng: -4.34}, 2);
However, I'd like a way to set the map view based on country codes, e.g. USA, JPN.
Is it possible to focus the map based on country codes?

A quick review of the Leaflet.js documentation did not turn up anything there that does this for you automatically.
If I understand your requirement properly, you want to set the view to a particular country and then zoom in on that country so that it takes up as much of the view as  possible.
There are many resources on the internet with the latitudes and longitudes and country codes, for example: here or here
However, the latitude and longitude coordinates are not enough on their own because you also need to know how much to zoom the map for each country. I had a quick look in the internet and could not find such a resource.
Below is one way to achieve what you want with a dropdown select button for three countries. I manually estimated the appropriate zoom level and added that to the countries object.


const countries = [{
    code: 'AUS',
    country: 'Australia',
    lat: -27.0,
    lng: 133.0,
    zoom: 4
  },
  {
    code: 'BMU',
    country: 'Bermuda',
    lat: 32.3333,
    lng: -64.75,
    zoom: 10
  },
  {
    code: 'CAN',
    country: 'Canada',
    lat: 60.0,
    lng: -95.0,
    zoom: 3
  },
];

const osm = L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

const countrySelector = document.getElementById("countries");
countrySelector.addEventListener("change", handleCountrySelect);

let foundCountry = countries.find((element) => element.code === 'AUS');
let foundCountryCoords = L.latLng(foundCountry.lat, foundCountry.lng);
let marker = null;

const map = L.map('worldmap', {
  center: foundCountryCoords,
  zoom: foundCountry.zoom,
  layers: [osm]
});

function handleCountrySelect() {
  let foundCountry = countries.find((element) => element.code === countrySelector.value);
  let foundCountryCoords = L.latLng(foundCountry.lat, foundCountry.lng)

  map.setView(foundCountryCoords).setZoom(foundCountry.zoom);

  if (marker) map.removeLayer(marker);

  marker = L.marker(foundCountryCoords);
  map.addLayer(marker);
}

handleCountrySelect();
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
}

select {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <select id="countries">
    <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
    <option value="BMU">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="worldmap" class="map"></div>



